# Outlook Script to process task updates

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I have a team of three that send email orders and quotes to a team of 96 sales reps.  We do this via Outlook tasks.

In Outlook 2007, we are noticing that a lot of the tasks are not updating/completing on our end.

So, I am running a script via Outlook rules to process all incoming task updates to see if this helps with the issue.

The code runs fine, but I get **`"rules in error:  The operation failed"`**, every few runs of the script.  Here is the macro I am using:

```
Sub taskupdateMacro(item As Outlook.MailItem)

 Dim olkApp, olkNS, olkTaskFolder, objItem, olkTaskUpdate, olkTask
 Dim objCount
 objCount = 0

 Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set olkNS = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 olkNS.Logon "Outlook"
 Set olkTaskFolder = olkNS.GetDefaultFolder(6)
 For Each objItem In olkTaskFolder.Items
     If (objItem.Class = 50 Or objItem.Class = 51 Or objItem.Class = 43) Then
        objCount = objCount + 1
        objItem.Display
        objItem.Close 1
     End If
 Next

 If objCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Task Related Emails to Open"
 End If

 Set objItem = Nothing
 Set olkTaskFolder = Nothing
 Set olkTaskRequest = Nothing
 Set olkTask = Nothing
 olkNS.Logoff
 Set olkNS = Nothing
 Set olkApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Edit your rule - Next - Select action `stop processing more rules` see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rules are unreliable but before trying ItemAdd or NewMailEx see what happens if you clean up your code.

Outlook is already running so you do not need CreateObject nor do you need Logon.

```
Sub taskupdateMacro(item As mailItem)

 'Dim olkApp

 Dim olkNS As Namespace
 Dim olkTaskFolder As folder
 Dim objItem As Object

 'Dim olkTaskUpdate
 'Dim olkTask As TaskItem

 Dim objCount As Long

 objCount = 0

 'Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 'Set olkNS = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

 Set olkNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

 'olkNS.Logon "Outlook"

 Set olkTaskFolder = olkNS.GetDefaultFolder(6)

 For Each objItem In olkTaskFolder.Items
     If (objItem.Class = 50 Or objItem.Class = 51 Or objItem.Class = 43) Then
     Debug.Print objItem.subject & " Class is: " & objItem.Class

        objCount = objCount + 1
        objItem.Display
        objItem.Close 1
     End If
 Next

 If objCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No Task Related Emails to Open"
 End If

 Set objItem = Nothing
 Set olkTaskFolder = Nothing

 'Set olkTaskRequest = Nothing
 'Set olkTask = Nothing
 'olkNS.Logoff

 Set olkNS = Nothing
 'Set olkApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on removing create object and logon.  Last thing, how can I alter the code to delete the mail item after the script opens/closes it?

Comment: You cannot delete effectively with a For Each loop. A downcount method is described here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262798/for-each-loop-not-deleting-all-emails