# process outlook task only if task is active

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro that processes all existing Tasks in Default Folder using "For Each", like in Code below.  However Problem is, that this processes also the Task that are already inactive (done). In my case I have 10,000 Tasks that are processes unnessarily. Any idea how to improve to do something like "for each, that is active..."?

```
Set olkApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")  
Set olkNS = olkApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
olkNS.Logon "Outlook"    
Set olkTaskFolder = olkNS.GetDefaultFolder(6)  
For Each objItem In olkTaskFolder.Items
```

similar to
[Outlook Script to process task updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35204617/outlook-script-to-process-task-updates)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if not objItem.Complete Then
```

or

you can avoid completed tasks at all using Restrict:

```
Set olkTaskFolder = olkNS.GetDefaultFolder(6)  
set objItems = olkTaskFolder.Items.Restrict("[Complete] = 'false' ")
For Each objItem In objItems
```